# I don't have flashlight icon on notification page

Tags: notification-bar

I just got lolipop on my note 4 bit it doesn't have the flashlight on the notifications quick page.  What's  up with that? is there a way I can get it?

Answer (score -1):

Try looking for it in the widegets section and add it from there.